# How to keep forked version of github sycned

Tags: github, android-studio, version-control, fork

I've forked a version of this

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-topeka

a few days ago.

I'm making changes to it in Android Studio. Now changes have been committed to the original project at

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-topeka

I want to merge my changes I've been making locally with that version. But at the same time I want to keep my version private?

How can I COMPARE  my changes locally with the master?

Comment: If you merge your changes with `master` then how can they remain private?

Comment: I guess I should have said I want to COMPARE with the master and update/merge my local so I can keep my changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, your workflow in GitHub will go something like this:

```
git pull origin master

# work work work

git commit -m 'I made some changes to android-topeka'

git pull origin master
# resolve merge conflicts

git push origin master
```

The general strategy is to commit your *local* changes, then `git pull` the remote to bring in any changes which other developers might have made to the android-topeka repository since you last pulled.  Once you have resolved the merge conflicts (if any), then you can fast-forward the branch on GitHub by doing a `git push`.

Note that origin points to https://github.com/googlesamples/android-topeka in your case.  I also assume that your local branch is called `master`, as I only see one `master` branch under the android-topeka project on GitHub.

Comment: Where am I committing my local changes? I don't want to check into https://github.com/googlesamples/android-topeka

Comment: `git commit` will update your _local_ repository with the changes.  Only `git pull` and `git push` will sync your local repository with the GitHub remote.

Comment: @stack Please review this answer and mark it correct if it solved your problem.